# How to detect if object has been changed in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got some hash oject with 5 fields: title, subject, content, author and date. I want to detect if object will be changed after 10 minutes. Of course I can just compare all fields, but I believe there is more suitable way to do it. $watch is not good solution, because, for example, title can be changed from "a" to "b", then from "b" to "a"; as you can see the value will be still "a" after 10 minutes. Is there any standard Angular way?

Comment: I need to detect changes after 10 minutes. I don't need every change always. $watch is bad choice for it

Comment: I apologise. I've redacted my close vote.

Comment: 10 minutes after what exactly, the first change or something else?

Comment: What do you want in the end? A list of every change that occured? Just `true`/`false` if any change has occured at all?

Comment: If value change from "a" to "b" then back to "a", is this considered a change or not?